# Installing ingress-nginx via Helm - error retrieving secret

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

We're trying to install the `ingress-nginx` controller onto an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster, following the steps from the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-internal-ip#create-an-ingress-controller).

Kubernetes version: 1.21.1
Chart version: 3.36.

The command we're using:

```
SET REGISTRY_NAME=
SET ACR_URL=%REGISTRY_NAME%.azurecr.io
SET CONTROLLER_REGISTRY=k8s.gcr.io
SET CONTROLLER_IMAGE=ingress-nginx/controller
SET CONTROLLER_TAG=v0.48.1
SET PATCH_REGISTRY=docker.io
SET PATCH_IMAGE=jettech/kube-webhook-certgen
SET PATCH_TAG=v1.5.1
SET DEFAULTBACKEND_REGISTRY=k8s.gcr.io
SET DEFAULTBACKEND_IMAGE=defaultbackend-amd64
SET DEFAULTBACKEND_TAG=1.5

SET NAMESPACE=ingress-basic

kubectl create namespace %NAMESPACE%
kubectl apply -n %NAMESPACE% -f .\limitRanges.yaml

helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx ^
    --namespace %NAMESPACE% ^
    --version 3.36.0 ^
    --set controller.replicaCount=2 ^
    --set controller.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux ^
    --set controller.image.registry=%ACR_URL% ^
    --set controller.image.image=%CONTROLLER_IMAGE% ^
    --set controller.image.tag=%CONTROLLER_TAG% ^
    --set controller.image.digest="" ^
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux ^
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.registry=%ACR_URL% ^
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.image=%PATCH_IMAGE% ^
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.tag=%PATCH_TAG% ^
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.digest="" ^
    --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux ^
    --set defaultBackend.image.registry=%ACR_URL% ^
    --set defaultBackend.image.image=%DEFAULTBACKEND_IMAGE% ^
    --set defaultBackend.image.tag=%DEFAULTBACKEND_TAG% ^
    --set defaultBackend.image.digest="" ^
    -f internal-load-balancer.yaml ^
    --debug
```

When running, the output is:

```
install.go:173: [debug] Original chart version: "3.36.0"
install.go:190: [debug] CHART PATH: C:\Users\......\AppData\Local\Temp\helm\repository\ingress-nginx-3.36.0.tgz

client.go:290: [debug] Starting delete for "nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission" ServiceAccount
client.go:319: [debug] serviceaccounts "nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission" not found
client.go:128: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:290: [debug] Starting delete for "nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission" ClusterRole
client.go:128: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:290: [debug] Starting delete for "nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission" ClusterRoleBinding
client.go:128: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:290: [debug] Starting delete for "nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission" Role
client.go:319: [debug] roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission" not found
client.go:128: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:290: [debug] Starting delete for "nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission" RoleBinding
client.go:319: [debug] rolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission" not found
client.go:128: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:290: [debug] Starting delete for "nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission-create" Job
client.go:319: [debug] jobs.batch "nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission-create" not found
client.go:128: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:519: [debug] Watching for changes to Job nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission-create with timeout of 5m0s
client.go:547: [debug] Add/Modify event for nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission-create: ADDED
client.go:586: [debug] nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission-create: Jobs active: 0, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
client.go:547: [debug] Add/Modify event for nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission-create: MODIFIED
client.go:586: [debug] nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission-create: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
```

If I look at the pod logs for the job `nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission-create`, I see the following log:

```
W0909 06:34:24.393154       1 client_config.go:608] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
{"err":"an error on the server (\"\") has prevented the request from succeeding (get secrets nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission)","level":"fatal","msg":"error getting secret","source":"k8s/k8s.go:109","time":"2021-09-09T06:34:34Z"}
```

I'm a little lost on where to look for additional information. I can see the error seems to be relating to getting a secret, and I can't see that secret under a `kubectl get secrets -A` command. I'm assuming the `\"\"` portion is supposed to be the error message, but it's not helping.

I have been able to install this chart successfully on a brand new, throwaway cluster. My guess is that it's an RBAC or permissions type problem, but without anything further about where to look, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Quote the Values. I would also suggest to simplify the code bcs all the values are set by default inside the [Helm Chart of ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml):

```
SET NAMESPACE=ingress-basic

kubectl create namespace %NAMESPACE%
kubectl apply -n %NAMESPACE% -f .\limitRanges.yaml

helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx ^
    --namespace %NAMESPACE% ^
    --version "4.0.1" ^
    -set controller.replicaCount="2" ^
    -f internal-load-balancer.yaml ^
    --debug
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Philip Welz. I've adjusted the command as you suggest (double-checking the values). I still need the `.image.registry` values as we're using a private registry, not the defaults. I'm seeing a slightly different error message now in the container log:
`{"err":"Get \"https://10.16.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/ingress-basic/secrets/nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission\": EOF","level":"fatal","msg":"error getting secret","source":"k8s/k8s.go:110","time":"2021-09-10T00:06:42Z"}`

Comment: what does the limitRanges.yaml do ? can you also check if the secret is present -> kubectl -n ingress-basic get secrets nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission

Comment: The `limitRanges.yaml` sets some default/min/max CPU and memory limits. Our cluster is enforcing that limits are always specified on every item, so without that the job doesn't get scheduled at all.

I've checked the secret, and it doesn't exist. I only have a `default-token-xxxxx`, `nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission-token-xxxxx` and a `sh.helm.release....` secret.

Comment: I would suggest to move all your settings to the values.yaml and do a -> helm upgrade -i ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx —namespace %NAMESPACE% -f values.yaml -f internal-load-balancer.yaml

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Philip Welz. I've made those changes but still no luck with the admission-create job.

Comment: can you send your values.yaml pls?